# Is my betta getting old or is he sick?

Tags: fish, betta

My Betta fish has white patches on his fins. One of the patches has a small whole in the middle. There are no signs of dulling scales, red/bulging eyes, or any other signs I found that could mean he is sick. The only other possible symptom he seems to have is that he like to sleep a lot but he has done that for the past one and a half years that I've had him. Is he getting old or is he just sick?

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to mine, I was told to treat it for "ich" short for Ichthyophthirius, if the treatment didnt work she was probably just getting old.

Mine, was just getting old, she lost almost all color. Changed from bright blue with red fins to almost a gold fish color all over. She live a year to a year and a half longer.

I hope you have as much luck as I did.